# Firestore data retrieval not "instantaneous"

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am working with Android Studio and I want to retrieve data from Firestore and use the document data as information for individual list items in the RecyclerView container.

Basically the components are an Activity consisting of a Fragment which houses the RecyclerView. This is the code I used in my Fragment to obtain and display the data (the one in the code is a sample):

```java
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_transport_requests_client, container, false);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        swipeContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);

        final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        DocumentReference documentReference = db.collection("transportRequests").document("T_client@eldereach.com_23 May 20 03:19 PM_");
        documentReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                    assert document != null;
                    list.add((String) document.getData().get("email"));

                }
            }
        });

        listAdapter = new TransportRequestsListAdapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

The issue here isn't that the code doesn't work, I think the retrieval works, however, nothing is displayed when the Fragment is launched. The data is only displayed when I click the Fragment. This doesn't occur when I just add random strings instead of data from the document, e.g. `list.add("random data")`. Any idea what is the issue here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The reason is that getting data from firebase is, of course, not instant -- it is asynchronous, which is why you need to set an "on complete listener" that runs when the transfer is complete, not instantly.  But in the very next line (which does run next, instantly), you assign the list object (which is empty because incomplete hasn't run yet) to the view.  make sense?

Comment: Ah! It makes so much sense now! Thank you! All I had to do was shift the last 4 lines into  onComplete.